# Determine if btrfs subvolume is read-only

Tags: btrfs

How can I tell if a `btrfs` subvolume is read-only or read-write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`btrfs property` will show the read-only / read-write status of a subvolume:

```
btrfs property get -ts /path/to/subvolume
```

This will give either: `ro=true` or `ro=false`.

Comment: This is a more direct way to know the read-only state, than the btrfs subvolume command, and you can also change it with `btrfs property set -ts /path/to/subvolume ro true` or `false`.

Comment: From what I can read from the documentation of `btrfs property get` this should be `btrfs property get -ts /path/to/subvolume ro`. Without the `ro` parameter it may return also information about label and compression. This might be important if one wants to use it in scripts.

Answer (score 2):

```
btrfs sub show /path/to/subvolume|grep readonly
```

returns 0 if it is readonly, you can test it with

```
btrfs sub show /path/to/subvolume|grep readonly && echo yep
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L! I'd suggest using `-q` with `grep`.